# Laravel 4: Eager loading

Tags: orm, laravel

I have a table called `UserWords` that has a `word_id` column in it, and I want to use that to get the row from the Words table, and kind of concatenate them together like a join. This way each one will have the info from the row in `UserWords` and `Words`. I defined the relation like so in `UserWord`:

```
class UserWord extends Eloquent{
    public function word(){
        $this->belongsTo('Word');
    }

}
```

and then after that, I try to get all the UserWords and Words like so:

```
$words = UserWord::with("word")->
                whereRaw("user_id = ".Auth::user()->id.
                " AND lang1 = '".$lang1.
                "' AND lang2 = '".$lang2."'")
                ->get();
```

This works if I don't have the with() in there. So, what am I doing wrong? Or am I going to have to create a raw `JOIN` to get what I want? I've never done relations before, so maybe I'm thinking of this fundamentally wrong? Either way, please teach me more than just giving the answer if you can! I read the docs and I think it should work, but it doesn't so... I'm asking here.

EDIT: 
The error I get is:

```
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Edited to include new information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of your relation is not correct, you have to return the result of the `belongsTo` method call. Try the following:

```php
class UserWord extends Eloquent {
    public function word(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Word');
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. Thanks. :P Also just out of curiosity, does it matter if I do with()->where()->get() or where()->with()->get() ?

Comment: The order of those chained method calls shouldn't influence the result, then until you call the get method, the query isn't assembled.

Answer (score 0):

```
$words = UserWord::with('word')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('lang1', $lang1)
    ->where('lang2', $lang2)
    ->get();
```

Comment: So I can't use whereRaw if I use with()?

Comment: I haven't used where raw but your query doesn't appear to require raw.

Comment: I see, I tried to change to how you had it, but it was still no good.

Comment: What does the "Word" model look like?

Comment: @peaceman just helped me out, i, like a moron forgot to return.